# NSURL returns nil when passing a HTTP url with a hostname with non-ascii characters

Tags: cocoa, foundation

If you attempt to create a `NSURL` from this URL, it returns `nil` (observed on OS X 10.11.6):

[http://夜景バーラウンジ-majestic汐留.com/](http://%E5%A4%9C%E6%99%AF%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B8-majestic%E6%B1%90%E7%95%99.com/)

The URL using the alternate representation of the hostname works fine:

http://xn---majestic-zv4hsg0krlzerfp952e1lybpewawh3b.com/

If all you have is the first version of the URL, is there any way to still make it work with `NSURL`?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/BigZaphod/IFUnicodeURL as this may do what you need.

Comment: `IFUnicodeURL` is old and needs to be updated for ARC but once that is done it converts your example URLs in both directions correctly.

Comment: Alternatively, https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/NSURL-IDN looks like a more modern option

Comment: IFUnicodeURL pulls in a massive amount of code for something this simple IMO, so I'd rather avoid this solution. NSURL-IDN seems quite better, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for most cases:

```
NSString *urlStr = @"http://夜景バーラウンジ-majestic汐留.com/";
urlStr = [stringToConvert stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
```

Comment: The returned `NSURL` is actually http://%E5%A4%9C%E6%99%AF%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B8-majestic%E6%B1%90%E7%95%99.com/ which happens to work in the browsers I tested. I'm suspicious though: is percent-encoding in the host name really something officially supported though?

Comment: Stack Overflow itself doesn't turn this URL into a link for instance.

Comment: Most modern webkit implementations support it since it got added to the ip spec in 2005: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt